# Google Cloud Storage confused about ACL/IAM and legacy permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-storage, roles, deprecated

I have a bucket whose contents I want to be publicly readable. However, I do not want the users to be able to list all of the contents by removing the keyname from the URL.

For the sake of simplicity, please assume that I am setting these permissions via the console.

1. Setting `Storage Object Viewer` for `allUsers` allows me to access the objects as well as list the contents.
2. Setttings `Storage Legacy Object Reader` for `allusers` allows me to access the objects but not list the contents.

This seems odd to me, why is the permission a "Legacy" permission? Does that mean it will be removed in future? This is a very important functionality for me.

Additionally, if it is not going to be removed, how can I ensure all future content published to this bucket inherits the bucket's permission?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is 'Legacy' because it exactly matches the pre-IAM permissions granted via the legacy READER role on an Object.

I can't say for certain what the plans are for those legacy roles (there are 5 of them), but if they are deprecated there would definitely need to be a deprecation period and an announcement.

If you are uncomfortable using a 'Legacy' role (or in any case where there is no curated role that exactly fits your use case) you can always create a custom role with exactly the set of permissions you need.
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles

As for 'how can I ensure all future content published to this bucket inherits the bucket's permission'.  The bucket IAM policy is always inherited by all objects in the bucket.  As you have a role granting the 'storage.objects.get' to allUsers on the bucket policy it will be applied to all objects in the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I also thought not just **"Storage Legacy Object Reader"** but also **"Storage Legacy Bucket Owner"**, **"Storage Legacy Bucket Reader"**, **"Storage Legacy Bucket Writer"** and **"Storage Legacy Object Owner"** were deprecated because they have **the word "Legacy"**.

[image]

But as long as I researched, they are not deprecated even now **"Apr, 2022"** which is **about 5 years after you asked this question**. I think they are kind of stable roles which are not easily and immediately deprecated.

If you are worried that they are deprecated sooner or later, you can create a custom role following [**this instruction "Creating a custom role"**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role).